# CUPS - install once, use another printer (of the same model) without re-configuring problem

Tags: printing, cups

For example I have "HP 1020 LaserJet" local USB printer successfully installed on a CUPS.

It uses one connection.

If I get another HP 1020 LaserJet printer it wouldn't print, I am having to 
modify the printer and change it's connection. Why?

How can I avoid this?

I know that it's illogical to use the same type printer on the same computer, but that's my environment.

How to make CUPS to use the same Connection for all printers of the same type, model, manufacturer etc.?

Thank you!!!

**EDIT:**

I have found out that it's not possible through the configs or any other standard ways.

The only way is to find a nice workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this, but here's what I suspect to be  the problem: `grep DeviceURI /etc/cups/printers.conf` yields `DeviceURI hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_1020?serial=XXXXXXX`.  The serial probably is printer-specific (not model-specific); don't know if it works without...

Comment: right, and the serials are different per each printer. There is also an UUID which is also unique but I think they are not printer specific - just random.

Comment: I tried to omit serial parameter - no print :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is in the UDEV rule.

Since it is not possible through standard ways.

You just create an UDEV rule which would detect printer adding
and then run lpadmin -p PRINTERNAME -v CONNECTION?serial=

so printer would be automatically reconfigured to use another connection.

P.S: I would give 300 of points if someone gave me right direction. I hope I will get my 300 back now :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my raspberry pi while working on a Kiosk application.
I found a possible solution, following the possible steps (the printer I am using is CUSTOM TG2460, in this case):

1. Run `lpinfo -v` which returns the list of devices attached.

```
network https
file cups-brf:/
direct vnc:/
network ipp
network beh
network ipps
network socket
network lpd
network http
direct hp
direct usb://CUSTOM%20SPA/TG2460-H?serial=TG2460-H_NUM:_0
direct hpfax
network dnssd://HP%20LaserJet%20200%20color%20M251n%20(E9A2D9)._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=564e4333-4230-3339-3439-a0d3c1e9a2d9
network dnssd://XEROX%20WorkCentre%203335%20(XRX9C934E79F15F)._printer._tcp.local/
network socket://192.168.10.12
network socket://192.168.10.123
network ipp://VodafonePS.local:631/ipp/print
network ipp://NPIE9A2D9.local:631/ipp/print
```

2. Filter for the line containing the printer you want and extract the device URI with `grep` and `cut`.

```
lpinfo -v | grep usb://CUSTOM | cut -d ' ' -f 2
>>> usb://CUSTOM%20SPA/TG2460-H?serial=TG2460-H_NUM:_0
```

3. Add the URI to the existing printer, updating the CUPS entry

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v usb://CUSTOM%20SPA/TG2460-H?serial=TG2460-H_NUM:_0
```

All can be summarized in this one liner:

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v $(lpinfo -v | grep usb://PRINTER_MODEL | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

I then run the command at each reboot. If a new printer is attached, the user must reboot the kiosk.
I think you can easily bind this to a UDEV rule and run when something changes on the printer that you want to swap.